# Creating a search box with results on map using php, pgadmin(SQL) and html

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, pgadmin

I would like to create a search box connected with my database in pgadmin which will show the results on map. 
My search.php (user-postgres,db-inz, schema-mru, table-skrzynki, column-size(range1-5)) :

```
<?php
$key=$_GET['key'];
$array = array();
$con=mysqli_connect("postgres","root","inz");
$query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from mru.skrzynki where size '%{$key}%'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $array[] = $row['size'];
}
echo json_encode($array);
mysqli_close($con);?>
```

This is a search box:

```
<div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="form-control search-menu" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Szukaj...">
                        <div class="search-box">
                        </div>
```

And that's my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'typeahead',
        remote:'search.php?key=%QUERY',
        limit : 10
    });
});
```

I suppose something went wrong with the connection... and the php question is incorrect. I'm really a beginner, so I will be grateful for any help :)

Comment: What is the result of your search?

Comment: As a result nothing appears....it looks like the search did not work. And there should be results as a scale of size 1 to 5

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit this line:

```
$query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from mru.skrzynki where size '%{$key}%'");
```

to this, just remove the { }:

```
$query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from mru.skrzynki where size=$key");
```

if size is a varchar type you can use this query:

```
$query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from mru.skrzynki where size like '%$key%'");
```

Comment: Still does not work... Even any errors in the console

Comment: I edited the query like this size=$key since size is numeric not string. If size is a varchar you can use like clause like so. where size like '%$key%'

Comment: It's numeric, and still nothing appears :D I have no experience in this (my first steps in php and mysqli) but maybe it's something wrong with the connection or showing the results...

Comment: Did you try to use this query? `$query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from mru.skrzynki where size like '%$key%'");`

Comment: Yes, thats result [link](https://uam-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/marwas4_st_amu_edu_pl/ES4uOiZ1X5FEsXI_eOn25qkB8OPKSU_ZXeJk97bCcnz6tQ?e=un2ERM)

Comment: try to put backtick on the size like this: `$query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from mru.skrzynki where \`size\` like '%$key%'");`